# When Printing From Dictionary, Getting One Letter At A Time

Tags: python, json

```
import json

f = open('csvjson.json')
data = json.load(f)

for i in data:
     for name in i['name']:
          print(name)
```

This is my JSON File:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w-r84H7vAy6VD9V_kP8wH63_J2jJBv86/view?usp=sharing

When I run the code from the main.py file, the output I get it:

https://pastebin.com/FSRd88KM

The code is like that, one letter per line, how would I fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to just print the whole name, not each letter of the name:

```py
for i in data:
     print(i['name'])
```

Comment: Just One More Question, How Would I Make A Variable From It?

Comment: Why do you need a variable? What are you going to do with the name?

Comment: So I Am Able To Print Out One Name At A Time.

Comment: But that is what the code does. It prints each name entry, one name on each line.

Comment: If I do that, it prints out one letter at a time